# How to center my overlay image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center my overlay image when the user clicks on one of my photos from my gallery. However, it seems to stay more towards the right even when I have `margin: 0 auto`. I'm not sure if I'm overriding something or one of my parent elements has a weird width.

My HTML:

```
<!-- Gallery -->
  <div id="photos">
    <ul id="photo-gallery">
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="images/header.jpg">
        <img src="images/header.jpg">
      </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
/* gallery */

#background {
  width: 100%;
}

#photos {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#overlay img {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 20% auto;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#photo-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#photo-gallery li {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#photo-gallery img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  opacity: 0.75;
}

#photo-gallery img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
// gallery

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  var $image = $("<img>");

  //An image to overlay
  $overlay.append($image);

  //Add overlay
  $("body").append($overlay);

    //click the image and a scaled version of the full size image will appear
    $("#photo-gallery a").click( function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");

      //update overlay with the image linked in the link
          $image.attr("src", imageLocation);

      //show the overlay
      $overlay.show();
    });

    $("#overlay").click(function() {
      $( "#overlay" ).hide();
    });
    $("#photos").slideDown(2000);
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. You must change `position: fixed;` to `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I have chage your code litle bit like -

```
#overlay img {
  width: 700px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

if you want to see then you can use this link -

https://jsbin.com/kexeham/edit?output